# Solving a system of non linear equations. Not sure if it's unsolvable due to insufficient information

Tags: systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-functions

**I'm not a mathematician or a math student, this is simply a problem I stumbled upon while working on a personal project, so excuse me if I seem ignorant**

First, I have the equation (1)
$$p_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \tanh{(-\frac{\theta_i + \theta_j}{2}  + 2Kp_{ij} )}  + 1 \right)$$
where $1 \leq i,j \leq N$. $N$ and $K$ are known quantities and $\theta_i, \theta_j$ are unknown.

The $N$ equations are $$C_i = \sum_{j\neq i}p_{ij}^*  = \frac{N-1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\neq i} \tanh{\left( - \frac{\theta_i + \theta_j}{2} + 2Kp_{ij}^* \right)}$$
where $C_i$ is a known quantity and $p_{ij}^*$ is the solution to the equation (1) given above.
I want to solve for $\theta_i, \theta_j$.

I don't necessarily need to solve this exactly, it can be done numerically.
I first tried to solve this problem by expanding the tanh to first order, which simply gives me a system of $N$ linear equations, but this wasn't very useful.

I feel as if this system of equations is only solvable if instead of the $2Kp_{ij}^*$ in the argument of the tanh, I had $2K\sum_{j\neq i}p_{ij}$. This way, I would have the value of $\sum_{j\neq i}p_{ij}^* = C_i (\textrm{given})$ for every $i$,  I could plug this value into the tanh, and then solve for $\theta_i$.

Is this problem solvable? Or do I not have enough information. To me it seems that I have $N$ unknown quantities ($\theta_i$) and $N$ equations, which should be doable. or am I missing something?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to know what you are doing, so we know where these equations come from. Are they all linearly independent?

Comment: Are there values of $C_i$ that you can solve for?  If so, is there hope of picking nearby values to that and solving numerically with Newton's method, nearby values that a next point and so on until you get to the values that you want?